# Ajustar el texto con el tamaño de la columna de una tabla

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

Tengo una tabla de la siguiente manera, donde se muestra los datos de la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es que la columna **Asignado a** sea de menor tamaño, es la única columna que tiene más dato, he intentado que quede de la siguiente manera. No eh podido lograrlo.
Estoy usando las clases *table-bordered* *table-hover* *table-condensed*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente Código de la tabla

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table style="width: 100%" id="table_principal" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> 
            Folio
          </th>
          <!-- <th >
            Contacto
          </th> -->
          <th >
            Nro Serie
          </th>
          <th >
            Marca
          </th>
          <th >
            Tipo
          </th>
          <th >
            Asignado a
          </th>
          <th >
            Solicitado
          </th>
          <th >
            Acciones
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Puedes intentar agregar una clase a tus `<td>` con la propiedad `white-space: nowrap;` o añadirlo directamente a la etiqueta. Céntanos cómo te va con eso. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: ¿La tabla toma todo el espacio del contenedor padre, o tiene un scroll horizontal? Porque si es lo primero, lo que podrías hacer es distribuir el 100% de ancho del contenedor de forma manual entre tus columnas (tanto de cabecera como de cuerpo) con el selector `:nth-child(n)`, donde `n` es el número de la columna seleccionada, de izquierda a derecha.

Comment: Tiene un scroll horizontal

Comment: Lo que hice fue utilizar `max-width; 50px`, pero ahora le letras están sobre encimadas, traté de poner  `white-space: nowrap` pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Buenas puedes utilizar la siguiente regla css en el td:

```
.celdaAsignado{
word-break: break-all !important;
white-space: nowrap !important;
width : 150px !important;
}
```

y la adjuntas de esta forma:

```
<td class="celdaAsignado">
Contenido
</td>
```

Saludos

Comment: Por favor evita usar la regla `!important` , se considera una mala práctica su uso excesivo